# Grails cannot clear a hasMany set using cascade

Tags: grails, grails-orm, cascading-deletes

I am trying to clear out the data from the `userDeptses` set but when I call the `clear()` method and try to save I get the following error

`Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: queued clear cannot be used with orphan delete`

I have the cascading set properly, I have even tried using just `delete-orphan` but still have issues.  All relevant classes have `equals` and `hashCode` methods implemented: `AppSystemUser` `UserDepts` `Department`

All documentation and articles I have read online say that using the combination of `clear()` and `all-delete-orphan` is supposed to work, but not for me.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Grails 3.1.4**

**Controller:**

```
AppSystemUser user = AppSystemUser.findBySystemUserid(cmd.netid);
user.userDeptses.clear();
userMgmtService.saveAppSystemUser(user);
```

**AppSystemUser:**

```
class AppSystemUser {

String systemUserid
String email
String fullName
Date lastLogin
Boolean active
Set appSystemUserRoles = [];
Set userCollegeses = [];
Set userDeptses = [];

static hasMany = [appSystemUserRoles: AppSystemUserRole,
                  applicationExtensions: ApplicationExtension,
                  userCollegeses: UserColleges,
                  userDeptses: UserDepts]

static mapping = {
    version false
    fullName column: 'fullName'
    lastLogin column: 'lastLogin'
    id name: "systemUserid", generator: "assigned"
    appSystemUserRoles cascade: "save-update, all-delete-orphan"
    userCollegeses cascade: "save-update, all-delete-orphan"
    userDeptses cascade: "save-update, all-delete-orphan"
}

....
```

**UserDept:**

```
class UserDepts {

Boolean active
AppSystemUser appSystemUser
Department department

static belongsTo = [AppSystemUser, Department]

static mapping = {
    version false
    appSystemUser column: "system_userid"
}

....
```

**UserMgmtService:**

```
@Transactional
class UserMgmtService {
    def saveAppSystemUser(AppSystemUser user) {
        user.save();
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like your `UserDepts` instances still have refs to `Department`. they need to be cleaned as well to get deleted as orphans

Comment: @injecteer I am not trying to delete the `Department`.  `UserDepts` just joins the 2 tables together but the `AppSystemUser` and `Department` data should remain intact after delete the join data.

Comment: that's what I said. the entries of your join table still have 1 end bound to Depatment. that's why the join entries are kept. in order to remove them, both relation side must be cleaned

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find out how to successfully use the `clear()` method of the Set so I just created a simple workaround that does the trick

```
def static hibernateSetClear(Set data) {
    if(data) {
        Iterator i = data.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext() && i.next()) {
            i.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Just iterate through the `Set` and remove each item individually.  This works perfect and I just call this method instead of `clear()` whenever I need to clear a `Set`